# mock typeorm findAndCount option's nested querybuilder

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs, typeorm

as you know typeorm find options, and specifically findAndCount, has a where option which takes a query builder as you can see in the [docs](https://typeorm.delightful.studio/interfaces/_query_builder_whereexpression_.whereexpression.html). it's really easy to user and create your custom query with it's query builder but the testing of it and mocking it, that is something i couldn't figure out how to do it. so the this is how i used it :

```
const options: FindManyOptions<UserEntity> = {
      join: {
        alias: 'User',
        innerJoinAndSelect: {
          userLogin: 'User.userLogin',
          payment: 'User.payment',
        },
      },
      where: (queryBuilder: SelectQueryBuilder<UserEntity>) => {
        queryBuilder.andWhere(`${queryBuilder.alias}.isManual = 1`);
        if (!filters) {
          return;
        }
        if (filters.id) {
          queryBuilder.andWhere(`${queryBuilder.alias}.id = :id`, { id: filters.id });
        }
        if (filters.userId) {
          queryBuilder.andWhere(`${queryBuilder.alias}.userId = :userId`, { userId: filters.userId });
        }
      },
      skip: paginationDto.skip,
      take: paginationDto.size,
    };

      options.order = { createdAt: 'DESC' };
    const [users, total] = await this._transactionOnlineRepository.findAndCount(options);
```

and this is how i tried to mock it :

```
    Const fakeQueryBuilder= {
join: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
where: (p)=> p.whereFactory(<SelectQueryBuilder<UserEntity>>{
 andWhere: jest.fn().mockReturnThis();
})}
const fakeUserRepo = {
findAndCount : jest.fn(()=>fakeQueryBuilder)
};
```

do you have any idea how to mock this or how to check if my filters are applied?

Answer (score 1):

```
const returnMock = 'test';
const subQueryMock = {
        select: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
        from: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
        where: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
        subQuery: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
        getQuery: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(returnMock)
      };

  const createQueryBuilderMock = {
    select: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    addSelect: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    innerJoin: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    innerJoinAndMapOne: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    where: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    andWhere: jest.fn(function (cb) {
      if (typeof cb === 'function') {
        cb(subQueryMock);
      }
      return this;
    }),
    setParameters: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    cache: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    insert: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    values: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    orIgnore: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    offset: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    limit: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    orderBy: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    getMany: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(returnMock),
    getManyAndCount: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(returnMock),
    execute: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(returnMock)
  };
```

I had a similar problem, I needed to mock subQuery, which I've solved like this. notice that mockReturnThis rewrite your instance

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. but the problem is as you see, the findAndCount takes a object like a normal find and then convert the object with properties like join and turn them into it's own query, the problem is finding out  how that callback converts the object to query and how to mock. it's like mocking the find function itself